# How can I download all the missing Python 3 standard modules?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, python3

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, a very recent convert from Windows 10. Python on Ubuntu is missing several standard modules, such as `Tkinter` and `distutils` (PyCharm needs it for creating venv interpreter). How can I add them to Ubuntu's Python? How many of these **standard** modules (compared to Windows version) are missing and can I get them all in one go?

Comment: People typically use Anaconda/Miniconda for getting all useful packages in one shot.

Comment: @turbulence If by people you mean Windows and Mac users then your comment is not incorrect.

Comment: @karel Even I, as an Ubuntu user, use Miniconda.

Comment: It's bad advice to recommend Anaconda to Ubuntu users.

Comment: You are pretending a standard that does not exist. The real [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) does not include either module. Ubuntu follows the real standard. If Python upstream changes their standard to include those modules, then Ubuntu will also include them.

Comment: @user535733, That's the closest to an answer I got. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 3):

Install Tkinter:

```
sudo apt install python-tk
```

Install Distutils:

```
sudo apt install -y python3-distutils
```

Comment: I know these commands. I want to know many are missing and whether I can download them all.

Comment: To be truth there are a lot of python modules (thousands of). Why would you install them all and waste your memory? Can you tell me what you are doing ? Then may be i could give you some suggestions!

Comment: I am not looking to install thousands of modules that maybe found at PyPi. I am talking about the **standard** libraries that are available when I install Python on Windows that includes ```tkinter``` and ```distutils```.

Comment: I'll second the answer from 5hifaT. It makes no sense to install the whole python universe. And it is not good idea to use Anaconda on Linux. The stuff is there, pick what you need and keep your system lean and mean. One of the big advantages of using Linux over windows.